# How to get the length of the code block's offset and line information in eclipse document?

Tags: eclipse, document, offset

when develop eclipse plugin,i encountered a problem like this:
i want get the offset and line of a code block in eclipse document, how do this?

code blcok like this

```
 text-decoration
```

and the document like this

```
body{background:#f0f1f1 url(../../../../../images/itbu/pm/itrade/v4/index_bg.png?v=20111102) repeat-x scroll 0px 41px;}
a:hover{text-decoration:underline;}
a b, a em, a span, a i{cursor:pointer;}
.clearFix{zoom:1;}
.clearFix:after{content:"\0020";display:block;height:0;clear:both;}
.Left{float:left;margin-bottom:3px;}
.Right{float:right;}
.Tc{text-align:center;}
.Tr{text-align:right;}
.Tl{text-align:left;}
```

if the code block is unique, i want get a line number and the offset in this line
best regards！